# Can I make fast user switching in Windows 7 show a list of users?

Tags: windows-7, user

Is there a way to "emulate" the fast user switching behaviour of Mac OS on Windows?

I'm already aware of the WIN+L shortcut, but is there a way to have Windows list the users and allowing one to switch to a user by simply clicking its icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It already does, on my computer. I can't take screenshots when at the login screen, otherwise I'd show you. I have three accounts - ZoFreX, Bob, and the guest account. If I lock the screen (Win+L) there is a button "Switch users" beneath the login prompt. If I click this, I see a list of the users on the system, and I can log in as them just by clicking (and typing in the password, if they have one). I can get directly to this screen by selecting "switch users" from the shutdown widget on the start menu.

I also found [instructions on creating a shortcut to go directly to the switch users screen](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/c4d01359-014d-4b08-a4aa-70ef633371ae).

Comment: As i plan to use that with my children, I would prefer not to go the shortcut way, but instead take the Fisher-Price route, with nice button in my task bar ;-)

Comment: If you made a shortcut to go to switch users, you could drag that onto the task bar for easy access :)

Comment: The problem is, Windows + L is not really a very fast way to swtich users.  You first get this locked screen to renter your password... why would you want to do that, to get back into the account you just switched from... with a switch button underneath.  So from keyboard Win +L, you now have to move your mouse to press the User Switch button, then move it again to select the account you want to switch to if you can quickly find its name against a busy background.   Not very fast at all.

Comment: Or you could use the TAB button.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like the XP-style behavior back, where `Win+L` goes to the Fast User Switching screen, you can emulate it with some creative use of Win 7's Task Scheduler.

Log into the account that needs this behavior, open Task Scheduler and create a new task.  Make sure that `Run only when user is logged on` is selected under `Security options`.  On the `Triggers` tab, create a new trigger for `On workstation lock` for the current user.  On the `Actions` tab, add an action to run the program `%SystemRoot%\System32\tsdiscon.exe`.  That's it!

AFAIK, because of the security boundaries between user accounts and sessions, the above is the only way to make this such that it works, and you have to create the task on every user account where you want this behavior to occur.  I don't think it's possible to create a single system-wide task for all users.